# How to iterate through every HTML table in a single HTML row

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I have a standard HTML `<table` inside an `ASP:Panel` control.
Inside this HTML table is a `<TR` row
And inside this TR row are severale tables.

```
    <asp:panel ID="PanelPreStart" runat="server" Visible="false" Enabled="false" Width="500px" >
        <table runat="server" id="tblPreStart">
    ...
    ...

      <tr id="trRiskMgt" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td colspan="2">
                <strong><big>** RISK MANAGEMENT **</big></strong>
                    <br /><br />
                <table id="tblHOC_MON" runat="server" visible="false">
..
..
                </table>

                <br />

                <table id="tblRMP_TUE" runat="server" visible="false" style="width: 100%; height: 114px; color: black; background-color: white;">
                    <tr>
...
... etc
```

How do I iterate through the `trRiskMgt` row to get to all the tables (`tblHOC_MON`, etc)?

I've tried this but it does not work. I get this error:

> CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow' because
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
    foreach (HtmlTableRow trow in trRiskMgt)
    {
        foreach (HtmlTable tbl in trow.Cells)
        {
            foreach (HtmlTableRow row in tbl.Controls)
            {
                foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
                    {
                        //CONTROL IS TEXBOXT: DISABLE CONTROL (NOT HIDE!)
                        if (ctrl is TextBox)
                        {
                            TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctrl;
                            txt.Enabled = wsDisable;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ideas for both JavaScript and C# code behind appreciated.

Thank you

**[UPDATE]**
I've managed to get around it by hardcoding one of the above tables into the code...

```
    foreach (HtmlTableRow row in tblHOC_MON.Rows)
    {
        foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
            {
                //CONTROL IS TEXBOXT: EXTRACT VALUES//
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctrl;
                    txt.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is obviously not ideal, as I will need to repeat this code multiple times for every table in the `TR` row.

But it will do for now.

Comment: For this to work, you have to specify `runat="server"` on all the tags you are trying to access from C#.

Comment: Look more closely. They already do have that.

Comment: No, you look more closely! `<td colspan="2">` see?

Comment: Also, when you say "but it does not work" - be more specific.

Comment: But the TR and the TABLE tags do have it. Are you saying everything inside the row has to have a server reference?

Comment: I get this error: "CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow' because 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inner html concept.

Example: 
to iterate particular html element say "table row" in your case, write below code on your controller:

```
trRiskMgt.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlEncode("your data");// elementId.InnerHtml
```

If you haven't specified any data it will show the single row in this case. 
AS the data will increase it will iterate the row.

You can further google HtmlEncode or Decode for better understanding.